# Axios send formData in controller return object object

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

//Vuejs2
//Laravel v7.x

I turn to you because I'm blocking, I can't find a solution.
I want to recover the data in my object in my controller.
In my View.vue I make an axios post

```
     data() {
        return {
          customer: {
             name: 'abc',
             login: 'def'
          },
          file: null
        }
    },methods: {
        submit(){
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("customer", this.customer);
            formData.append("file", this.file);

            axios.post('/project/new',
                        formData, {
                            headers: {
                                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                            }
                        }).then(data => {
                        console.log(data.data);
                    });
        }
    }
```

I collect like that in my controller

```
public function postProject(Request $request)
{
    return $request->customer;  //return [Object Object]
    return $request->customer->name;  //return Trying to get property 'name' of non-object
    return $request->customer['name']; //return Illegal string offset 'name'
    return $request->file;  //return [Object Object]
}
```

Thx for help. have a nice day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `.append` to add objects to your FormData.

Looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append the method only accepts an USVString or Blob as the value. Everything else is casted to String.

And the string representation of a standard object in Javascript is `[object Object]`.

You can try `JSON.stringify(this.customer)` to convert it to its JSON representation.

Comment: I really want to thank you! it finally works! other quick question do I need JSON.stringify if I send files?

Comment: To send a File you have to pass an instance of the `File` class to FormData https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/File

Answer (score -2):

Try $request->get('customer') or $request->input('customer')